# What is the 'global' object in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this, global

I've just seen a weird behaviour of the `this` keyword in NodeJS environment. I'm listing them with code. I've run this code with `NodeJS v6.x`, with a single `JavaScript` file.

While testing with one line of code as follows, whether with or without the `'use strict'` statement, this points to an empty object `{}`.

```
console.log(this)
```

But, when I'm running the statement within a self executing function like,

```
(function(){
  console.log(this);
}());
```

It's printing a really big object. Seems to me the Global execution context object created by `NodeJS` environment.

And while executing the above function with a `'use strict'` statement, expectedly it's printing `undefined`

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  console.log(this);
}());
```

But, while working with browser (I've tested only with `Chrome`), the first three examples yield the `window` object and the last one gave `undefined` as expected.

The behaviour of the browser is quite understandable. But, in case of `NodeJS`, does it not create the execution context, until I'm wrapping inside a function?

So, most of the code in `NodeJS` runs with an empty **global** `object`?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions

Answer (score 76, accepted):

While in browsers the global scope is the `window` object, in nodeJS the global scope of a module is the module itself, so when you define a variable in the global scope of your nodeJS module, it will be local to this module.

You can read more about it in the **[NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)** where it says:

> **global**
>
> `<Object> The global namespace object.`
>
> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
>   in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a
>   global variable. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is
>   not the global scope; var something inside an Node.js module will be
>   local to that module.

And in your code when you write:

- `console.log(this)` in an empty js file(module) it will print an empty object `{}` referring to your empty module.
- `console.log(this);` inside a self invoking function, `this` will point to the global nodeJS scope object which contains all NodeJS common properties and methods such as `require()`, `module`, `exports`, `console`...
- `console.log(this)` with [**strict mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) inside a self invoking function it will print `undefined` as a self invoked function doesn't have a default local scope object in [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: "... will print an empty object {} referring to your empty module."      That is somewhat misleading. A better answer is by Willem van der Veen below.  The value of this which is { }  does NOT refer to the "module" but  to the current "module.exports" -object.   The module (-object) itself  is not "empty" since it has the property 'exports' whose value is an Object with no local properties,  sometimes referred to as an "empty object".  But even such an "empty" object {}  is really not "empty" because it does have inherited properties such as its method "toString()".

Comment: @PanuLogic the statement is totally `logic`, if you would like to be logic and it's not misleading, it's the facts here, **and the properties you are talking about are always inherited by all objects, it's not worthy mentionning them**, by the way it's the Docs spécification. And **we are here talking about `this` or Global object in nodejs and not Javascript `object` definition** so we should focus on that point   :)

Answer (score 94):

### Value of `this` in a node module:

`this` in NodeJS **global scope** is the current module.exports object, not the global object. This is different from a browser where the global scope is the global `window` object. Consider the following code executed in Node:

```
console.log(this);    // logs {}

module.exports.foo = 5;

console.log(this);   // log { foo:5 }
```

First we log an empty object because there are no values in `module.exports` in this module. Then we put `foo` on the `module.exports` object, when we then again log `this` we can see that it now logs the updated `module.exports` object.

### How can we access the `global` object:

We can access the `global` object in node using the `global` keyword:

```
console.log(global);
```

The `global` object exposes a variety of useful properties about the environment. Also this is the place where functions as `setImmediate` and `clearTimeout` are located.

Comment: This was the answer I actually needed.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer I would say, although the title of the answer is about a slightly different question ("Value of this in a node module...") than originally asked.  Still most helpful for understanding it all emphasizing that 'this' and 'global object' are two different things not only in Node.js but in JavaScript in general

Comment: If you want a reference to the global object that works in any context, you can read `this` from a directly-called function. `const global = (function() {return this})();`. This evaluates to `window` in the browser, `self` in a service worker and `global` in nodejs.

Comment: The major con of accessing the '__global scope__' inside a traditional function as Joseph has stated is that you will get undefined when using `strict mode`. I recommend using `globalThis` property. In this way, you can always reference the global object in a consistent manner without having to know which environment the code is being run in (such as in browser, web worker, Nodejs, e.t.c ) or the current execution context (scope)

Answer (score 9):

Very interesting:

```
var JSON = require('circular-json');

console.log('1) ' + JSON.stringify(this, null, 2));

(function(){
    console.log('2) ' + JSON.stringify(this, null, 2));
}());

(function(){
  'use strict';
   console.log('3) ' + JSON.stringify(this, null, 2));
}());
```

will produce:

```
1) {}


2) {
  "global": "~",
  "process": {
    "title": "node",
    "version": "v6.9.1",
    "moduleLoadList": [
      "Binding contextify",
      "Binding natives",
      "NativeModule events",
      "NativeModule util",
      "Binding uv",
      "NativeModule buffer",
      "Binding buffer",
      "Binding util",
      "NativeModule internal/util",
      "NativeModule timers",
      "Binding timer_wrap",
      "NativeModule internal/linkedlist",
      "NativeModule assert",
      "NativeModule internal/process",
      "Binding config",
      "NativeModule internal/process/warning",
      "NativeModule internal/process/next_tick",
      "NativeModule internal/process/promises",                                                                                                              
      "NativeModule internal/process/stdio",                                                                                                                 
      "Binding constants",                                                                                                                                   
      "NativeModule path",                                                                                                                                   
      "NativeModule module",                                                                                                                                 
      "NativeModule internal/module",                                                                                                                        
      "NativeModule vm",                                                                                                                                     
      "NativeModule fs",                                                                                                                                     
      "Binding fs",                                                                                                                                          
      "NativeModule stream",                                                                                                                                 
      "NativeModule _stream_readable",                                                                                                                       
      "NativeModule internal/streams/BufferList",                                                                                                            
      "NativeModule _stream_writable",                                                                                                                       
      "NativeModule _stream_duplex",                                                                                                                         
      "NativeModule _stream_transform",                                                                                                                      
      "NativeModule _stream_passthrough",                                                                                                                    
      "Binding fs_event_wrap",                                                                                                                               
      "NativeModule console",                                                                                                                                
      "Binding tty_wrap",                                                                                                                                    
      "NativeModule tty",                                                                                                                                    
      "NativeModule net",                                                                                                                                    
      "NativeModule internal/net",                                                                                                                           
      "Binding cares_wrap",                                                                                                                                  
      "Binding tcp_wrap",                                                                                                                                    
      "Binding pipe_wrap",                                                                                                                                   
      "Binding stream_wrap",                                                                                                                                 
      "Binding signal_wrap"                                                                                                                                  
    ],                                                                                                                                                       
    "versions": {                                                                                                                                            
      "http_parser": "2.7.0",                                                                                                                                
      "node": "6.9.1",                                                                                                                                       
      "v8": "5.1.281.84",                                                                                                                                    
      "uv": "1.9.1",                                                                                                                                         
      "zlib": "1.2.8",                                                                                                                                       
      "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",                                                                                                                                  
      "icu": "57.1",                                                                                                                                         
      "modules": "48",                                                                                                                                       
      "openssl": "1.0.2j"                                                                                                                                    
    },                                                                                                                                                       
    "arch": "x64",                                                                                                                                           
    "platform": "linux",                                                                                                                                     
    "release": {                                                                                                                                             
      "name": "node",                                                                                                                                        
      "lts": "Boron",                                                                                                                                        
      "sourceUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.9.1/node-v6.9.1.tar.gz",
      "headersUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.9.1/node-v6.9.1-headers.tar.gz"
    },
    "argv": [
      "/usr/local/bin/node",
      "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/thistest.js"
    ],
    "execArgv": [],
    "env": {
      "NVM_DIR": "/home/froth/.nvm",
      "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/opt/opencascade/lib",
      "CSF_UnitsDefinition": "/opt/opencascade/src/UnitsAPI/Units.dat",
      "CSF_GraphicShr": "/opt/opencascade/lib/libTKOpenGl.so",
      "CSF_EXCEPTION_PROMPT": "1",
      "LANG": "de_DE.UTF-8",
      "PROFILEHOME": "",
      "DISPLAY": ":0",
      "SHELL_SESSION_ID": "09b6f0f3b1d94c5f8aba3f8022075677",
      "NODE_PATH": "/usr/lib/node_modules",
      "COLORTERM": "truecolor",
      "NVM_CD_FLAGS": "",
      "MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH": "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins",
      "CSF_IGESDefaults": "/opt/opencascade/src/XSTEPResource",
      "CSF_XCAFDefaults": "/opt/opencascade/src/StdResource",
      "XDG_VTNR": "1",
      "PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN": "/tmp/kwallet5_froth.socket",
      "CSF_STEPDefaults": "/opt/opencascade/src/XSTEPResource",
      "XDG_SESSION_ID": "c2",
      "CSF_XSMessage": "/opt/opencascade/src/XSMessage",
      "USER": "froth",
      "DESKTOP_SESSION": "/usr/share/xsessions/awesome",
      "GTK2_RC_FILES": "/home/froth/.gtkrc-2.0",
      "PWD": "/home/froth/freelancer-projects",
      "HOME": "/home/froth",
      "XDG_SESSION_TYPE": "x11",
      "CSF_PluginDefaults": "/opt/opencascade/src/StdResource",
      "XDG_DATA_DIRS": "/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop",
      "NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR": "https://iojs.org/dist",
      "KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION": "/Sessions/1",
      "XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP": "",
      "CSF_StandardDefaults": "/opt/opencascade/src/StdResource",
      "CSF_StandardLiteDefaults": "/opt/opencascade/src/StdResource",
      "MMGT_CLEAR": "1",
      "KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW": "/Windows/1",
      "CSF_UnitsLexicon": "/opt/opencascade/src/UnitsAPI/Lexi_Expr.dat",
      "GTK_MODULES": "canberra-gtk-module",
      "MAIL": "/var/spool/mail/froth",
      "NVM_RC_VERSION": "",
      "CSF_XmlOcafResource": "/opt/opencascade/src/XmlOcafResource",
      "TERM": "xterm-256color",
      "SHELL": "/bin/bash",
      "KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE": ":1.23",
      "XDG_SESSION_CLASS": "user",
      "XDG_SEAT_PATH": "/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0",
      "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP": "",
      "QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON": "1",
      "KONSOLE_PROFILE_NAME": "Shell",
      "CASROOT": "/opt/opencascade",
      "NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR": "https://nodejs.org/dist",
      "COLORFGBG": "15;0",
      "XDG_SEAT": "seat0",
      "SHLVL": "2",
      "LANGUAGE": "",
      "WINDOWID": "29360134",
      "LOGNAME": "froth",
      "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS": "unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus",
      "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR": "/run/user/1000",
      "CSF_MDTVTexturesDirectory": "/opt/opencascade/src/Textures",
      "XAUTHORITY": "/home/froth/.Xauthority",
      "XDG_SESSION_PATH": "/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1",
      "PATH": "/home/froth/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/opt/opencascade/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl",
      "CSF_LANGUAGE": "us",
      "CSF_SHMessage": "/opt/opencascade/src/SHMessage",
      "OLDPWD": "/home/froth",
      "_": "/usr/local/bin/node"
    },
    "pid": 4658,
    "features": {
      "debug": false,
      "uv": true,
      "ipv6": true,
      "tls_npn": true,
      "tls_alpn": true,
      "tls_sni": true,
      "tls_ocsp": true,
      "tls": true
    },
    "_needImmediateCallback": false,
    "execPath": "/usr/local/bin/node",
    "debugPort": 5858,
    "_events": {
      "SIGWINCH": [
        null,
        null
      ]
    },
    "_eventsCount": 4,
    "domain": null,
    "_exiting": false,
    "config": {
      "target_defaults": {
        "cflags": [],
        "default_configuration": "Release",
        "defines": [],
        "include_dirs": [],
        "libraries": []
      },
      "variables": {
        "asan": 0,
        "debug_devtools": "node",
        "force_dynamic_crt": 0,
        "gas_version": "2.23",
        "host_arch": "x64",
        "icu_data_file": "icudt57l.dat",
        "icu_data_in": "../../deps/icu-small/source/data/in/icudt57l.dat",
        "icu_endianness": "l",
        "icu_gyp_path": "tools/icu/icu-generic.gyp",
        "icu_locales": "en,root",
        "icu_path": "deps/icu-small",
        "icu_small": true,
        "icu_ver_major": "57",
        "node_byteorder": "little",
        "node_enable_d8": false,
        "node_enable_v8_vtunejit": false,
        "node_install_npm": true,
        "node_module_version": 48,
        "node_no_browser_globals": false,
        "node_prefix": "/",
        "node_release_urlbase": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/",
        "node_shared": false,
        "node_shared_cares": false,
        "node_shared_http_parser": false,
        "node_shared_libuv": false,
        "node_shared_openssl": false,
        "node_shared_zlib": false,
        "node_tag": "",
        "node_use_bundled_v8": true,
        "node_use_dtrace": false,
        "node_use_etw": false,
        "node_use_lttng": false,
        "node_use_openssl": true,
        "node_use_perfctr": false,
        "node_use_v8_platform": true,
        "openssl_fips": "",
        "openssl_no_asm": 0,
        "shlib_suffix": "so.48",
        "target_arch": "x64",
        "uv_parent_path": "/deps/uv/",
        "uv_use_dtrace": false,
        "v8_enable_gdbjit": 0,
        "v8_enable_i18n_support": 1,
        "v8_inspector": true,
        "v8_no_strict_aliasing": 1,
        "v8_optimized_debug": 0,
        "v8_random_seed": 0,
        "v8_use_snapshot": true,
        "want_separate_host_toolset": 0
      }
    },
    "stdout": {
      "connecting": false,
      "_hadError": false,
      "_handle": {
        "bytesRead": 0,
        "_externalStream": {},
        "fd": 9,
        "writeQueueSize": 0,
        "owner": "~process~stdout"
      },
      "_parent": null,
      "_host": null,
      "_readableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 16384,
        "buffer": {
          "head": null,
          "tail": null,
          "length": 0
        },
        "length": 0,
        "pipes": null,
        "pipesCount": 0,
        "flowing": null,
        "ended": false,
        "endEmitted": false,
        "reading": false,
        "sync": true,
        "needReadable": false,
        "emittedReadable": false,
        "readableListening": false,
        "resumeScheduled": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "ranOut": false,
        "awaitDrain": 0,
        "readingMore": false,
        "decoder": null,
        "encoding": null
      },
      "readable": false,
      "domain": null,
      "_events": {},
      "_eventsCount": 3,
      "_writableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 16384,
        "needDrain": false,
        "ending": false,
        "ended": false,
        "finished": false,
        "decodeStrings": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "length": 0,
        "writing": false,
        "corked": 0,
        "sync": false,
        "bufferProcessing": false,
        "writecb": null,
        "writelen": 0,
        "bufferedRequest": null,
        "lastBufferedRequest": null,
        "pendingcb": 1,
        "prefinished": false,
        "errorEmitted": false,
        "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
        "corkedRequestsFree": {
          "next": null,
          "entry": null
        }
      },
      "writable": true,
      "allowHalfOpen": false,
      "destroyed": false,
      "_bytesDispatched": 6,
      "_sockname": null,
      "_writev": null,
      "_pendingData": null,
      "_pendingEncoding": "",
      "server": null,
      "_server": null,
      "columns": 84,
      "rows": 84,
      "_type": "tty",
      "fd": 1,
      "_isStdio": true
    },
    "stderr": {
      "connecting": false,
      "_hadError": false,
      "_handle": {
        "bytesRead": 0,
        "_externalStream": {},
        "fd": 11,
        "writeQueueSize": 0,
        "owner": "~process~stderr"
      },
      "_parent": null,
      "_host": null,
      "_readableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 16384,
        "buffer": {
          "head": null,
          "tail": null,
          "length": 0
        },
        "length": 0,
        "pipes": null,
        "pipesCount": 0,
        "flowing": null,
        "ended": false,
        "endEmitted": false,
        "reading": false,
        "sync": true,
        "needReadable": false,
        "emittedReadable": false,
        "readableListening": false,
        "resumeScheduled": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "ranOut": false,
        "awaitDrain": 0,
        "readingMore": false,
        "decoder": null,
        "encoding": null
      },
      "readable": false,
      "domain": null,
      "_events": {},
      "_eventsCount": 3,
      "_writableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 16384,
        "needDrain": false,
        "ending": false,
        "ended": false,
        "finished": false,
        "decodeStrings": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "length": 0,
        "writing": false,
        "corked": 0,
        "sync": true,
        "bufferProcessing": false,
        "writecb": null,
        "writelen": 0,
        "bufferedRequest": null,
        "lastBufferedRequest": null,
        "pendingcb": 0,
        "prefinished": false,
        "errorEmitted": false,
        "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
        "corkedRequestsFree": {
          "next": null,
          "entry": null
        }
      },
      "writable": true,
      "allowHalfOpen": false,
      "destroyed": false,
      "_bytesDispatched": 0,
      "_sockname": null,
      "_writev": null,
      "_pendingData": null,
      "_pendingEncoding": "",
      "server": null,
      "_server": null,
      "columns": 84,
      "rows": 84,
      "_type": "tty",
      "fd": 2,
      "_isStdio": true
    },
    "stdin": {
      "connecting": false,
      "_hadError": false,
      "_handle": {
        "bytesRead": 0,
        "_externalStream": {},
        "fd": 12,
        "writeQueueSize": 0,
        "owner": "~process~stdin",
        "reading": false
      },
      "_parent": null,
      "_host": null,
      "_readableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 0,
        "buffer": {
          "head": null,
          "tail": null,
          "length": 0
        },
        "length": 0,
        "pipes": null,
        "pipesCount": 0,
        "flowing": null,
        "ended": false,
        "endEmitted": false,
        "reading": false,
        "sync": false,
        "needReadable": true,
        "emittedReadable": false,
        "readableListening": false,
        "resumeScheduled": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "ranOut": false,
        "awaitDrain": 0,
        "readingMore": false,
        "decoder": null,
        "encoding": null
      },
      "readable": true,
      "domain": null,
      "_events": {},
      "_eventsCount": 4,
      "_writableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 0,
        "needDrain": false,
        "ending": false,
        "ended": false,
        "finished": false,
        "decodeStrings": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "length": 0,
        "writing": false,
        "corked": 0,
        "sync": true,
        "bufferProcessing": false,
        "writecb": null,
        "writelen": 0,
        "bufferedRequest": null,
        "lastBufferedRequest": null,
        "pendingcb": 0,
        "prefinished": false,
        "errorEmitted": false,
        "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
        "corkedRequestsFree": {
          "next": null,
          "entry": null
        }
      },
      "writable": false,
      "allowHalfOpen": false,
      "destroyed": false,
      "_bytesDispatched": 0,
      "_sockname": null,
      "_writev": null,
      "_pendingData": null,
      "_pendingEncoding": "",
      "server": null,
      "_server": null,
      "isRaw": false,
      "isTTY": true,
      "fd": 0
    },
    "argv0": "node",
    "mainModule": {
      "id": ".",
      "exports": {},
      "parent": null,
      "filename": "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/thistest.js",
      "loaded": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/node_modules/circular-json/build/circular-json.node.js",
          "exports": {},
          "parent": "~process~mainModule",
          "filename": "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/node_modules/circular-json/build/circular-json.node.js",
          "loaded": true,
          "children": [],
          "paths": [
            "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/node_modules/circular-json/build/node_modules",
            "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/node_modules/circular-json/node_modules",
            "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/node_modules",
            "/home/froth/node_modules",
            "/home/node_modules",
            "/node_modules"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "paths": [
        "/home/froth/freelancer-projects/node_modules",
        "/home/froth/node_modules",
        "/home/node_modules",
        "/node_modules"
      ]
    }
  },
  "console": {}
}


3) undefined
```

In `3)` **this** is **undefined** as it is not autoboxed to an object in strict mode. That means that there is no root object in this context. If you do not use strict mode then your code is boxed by a parent scope.As you can see in the output, within nodejs there is lot of information about node internal stuff.

In `1)` the output is an empty object because in the top-level code in a node module, this is the equivalent to module.exports and module.exports is empty in this example.

Comment: All those _enclosures_, _function constructions _and _stricts_ just give an illusion of safety.
One can still access: **global**, **process**...
Just try any of them in place of **this**:
`(function(){
  'use strict';
   console.log('3) ' + JSON.stringify(process, null, 2));
}());`

Answer (score 8):

To start with [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global) on Global context in node environment

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node.JS this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node.JS module will be local to that module.

Each JS file is treated as a module. Node automatically wraps the code of a JS file in a self [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) with `exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname` as parameters to the function.

**Below is the screenshot of execution context using `node-debug`**

[image: node-debug]

If you run the below code, prints `true` which means `this` refers to `exports`  in node.js. Best explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486261/1848109).

```
console.log(this === exports);
```

Which means at execution the code is wrapped something similar as below in Node.js separating your code from global context using a [**wrapper function context or IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) technique hypothetically.

```
  var context = (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
       console.log(this) //This is my code
  });
    
  /** hypothetical module wrapper code **/

  var module = {exports:{}};
  context.apply(module.exports, [module.exports, require, module, "FILE_NAME", "DIR_NAME"]);
```

---

Answer to the next point refer this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) completely:

> A function's `this` keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode.

so when you execute this code

```
(function(){
  console.log(this);
}());
```

prints the `global` object and in [`use strict`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) mode prints `undefined`

---

**Remember:**

In browser the function is not wrapped by [IIFE wrapper function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) context as done in Node.JS, it's directly executed on `window` object. Hence the calling context varies for Node.JS and Browser.

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22771432/1848109) article.

Answer (score 6):

Here i want to highlight one property of global !

> What you put there is accessible also directly

(make sure to check the Property title and section)

Before bringing the property! Let's **define global again!**

**global** is a **language keyword** specific to nodejs and reference **The global namespace object**

As it was already described on other answers! The top scope in a module! Is not global! And limited to only that module!

So when you declare a variable in one module you can't access it in another!

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

The **global namespace** is accessible everywhere in a given process! In all modules! That's include your own module and third party modules!

console Logging global in node repl will give this:

```
Welcome to Node.js v13.14.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> console.log(global)
<ref *1> Object [global] {
  global: [Circular *1],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
undefined
```

### The property: What you put there is accessible also directly

What i wanted to bring is this! I get to notice this when i was exploring **laravel-mix** code source!

> If you set something on the **global** object! as like `global.Hola = { print: () => console.log("Hola") };`. Then you can access the variable by it's name directly any where in the project code (multiple files [modules] & Whole node process code)! Meaning `Hola.print()` in place of `global.Hola.print()`!

Here a node repl screenshot for the example above:

```
> global.Hola = { print: () => console.log('Hola') }
{ print: [Function: print] }
> Hola.print()
Hola
undefined
```

[image]

Nice property ! That's the global namespace!

You can notice the methods like `clearInteraval`, `clearTimeout`, `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, ... are defined there! And we used to access them directly by there name!

### Laravel mix example

Here some examples from laravel-mix code source! Where it use that!

If you open this file:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js

You notice in the import section there is no! `Mix` variable neither `Config`!
But they are used and part of the code! I was like: `what the heck`!

Imort code:

```js
let Assert = require('../Assert');
let Dependencies = require('../Dependencies');
let mergeWebpackConfig = require('../builder/MergeWebpackConfig');
```

On line 68 : ([link here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js#L68)) you can see the usage of `Mix` class variable!

[image]

And same thing for `Config` at line 178 ([link here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js#L178))

[image]

When i first got to see it! And get to check the import section! And using github reference feature (came with nothing)! I was `What the heck`!

Later on when i checked the [Mix.js](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/Mix.js#L249) file! And class! I found the code that set them! I got the intuition and googled after!

[image]

### Conflicts and Why one would want to use the global namespace

A problem to setting globals is overriding and conflicts! Which leads to bugs and unexpected behaviors, up to a total crash! If modules start to use it without thoughts! One module will screw it for another! Like when using a third party module! Imagine module `request` will set **Config var**! And you set it too! Or even another third party module! And they are all dependent on it! One will screw it for the other module!

So simply put! We should not use globals! **No no**! **And yes**!

It all depends!

It's preferable for a module to not do! That way the module is completly isolated! And it's more robust! Generally setting the variable in a certain module! And importing it each time! Using dependency injection ...etc

In many cases however it's **more flexible** to use the global namespace!

You can do so and not worry! If you are **building a server**! **Config object** can go on the global! A **command line Interface tool or script**! Some process that run directly!

Generally **don't use the global scope** when you are **building a module**! **A package**! **A library**! **A component**! **Which gonna be reusable**! (**Reusable cross projects**! no global scope! isolate it)!

**Laravel mix** for instance is a package that is used to generate webpack config! That get to run as a cli tool and process!

**However** if the **Config** variable for example was also set by Webpack or some of the community plugins or loaders! Then **problems** can occure due to overriding!

Something simple could make it **safer** is to **add** a **domain** in the **naming**! For instance `Mix_Config` !

Answer (score 4):

`global` is a reference to the real global scope object in NodeJS, somewhat like using `window` in a browser JS environment.

```
global.studentName = 'Kyle'

console.log(`Hello, ${ global.studentName }!`)
// Hello, Kyle!

console.log(`Hello, ${ studentName }!`)
// Hello, Kyle!
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a comprehensive answer that covers the value of `this` in different contexts. Explanation is added as code comments where needed.

```js
let this_in_objects = {
    propA: "let's figure THIS out!",
    /*
    * Object property set to a standard function.
    * */
    propB: function () {
        return this.propA;
        // Returns the value of this_in_objects.propA as expected.
    },
    /*
    * Object property set to an arrow function (Introduced in ES6).
    * */
    propC: () => {
        return this.propA;
        // Should return 'undefined'
        // In this case, 'this' refers to the surrounding scope, which could be one of the following :
        // - 'module.exports' if the code is inside a nodejs module.
        // - 'window' if the code is executed in a browser, or 'undefined' if running in a terminal due to the lack of 'window' global variable.
    },
    /*
    * Object property set to a standard function that returns an arrow function.
    * */
    propD: function () {
        let newArrowFunction = () => {
            return this.propA;
            // Returns the value of this_in_objects.propA.
            // The first functions declaration binds 'this' to the current object
            // then the second function scope is now the 'this' of the first function.

        }
        return newArrowFunction;
    },
    /*
    * Object property set another object with 2 properties, one of which returns a standard function.
    * */
    propE: {
        propE_1: "value of propE.propE_1",
        propE_2: function () {
            return this.propE_1;
            // In this case, 'this' refers to the surrounding scope, which is the parent object 'propE'
        }
    },
    /*
    * Object property set another object with 2 properties, one of which returns an arrow function.
    * */
    propF: {
        propF_1: "value of propF.propF_1",
        propF_2: () => {
            return this.propF_1;
            // Should return 'undefined'
            // There no change in the binding of 'this', so
            // In this case, 'this' refers to the surrounding scope, which could be one of the following :
            // - 'module.exports' if the code is inside a nodejs module.
            // - 'window' if the code is executed in a browser, or 'undefined' if running in a terminal due to the lack of 'window' global variable.
        }
    },
};

console.log(this_in_objects.propB());
// Returns "let's figure THIS out!"

console.log(this_in_objects.propC());
// Returns 'undefined'

console.log(this_in_objects.propD()());
// Returns "let's figure THIS out!"
// Notice the double round brackets to call the nested anonymous functions.

console.log(this_in_objects.propE.propE_2());
// Returns "value of propE.propE_1"

console.log(this_in_objects.propF.propF_2());
// Returns 'undefined'


this_in_objects.propX = function () {
    return this.propA;
    // Returns the value of this_in_objects.propA as expected.
};
this_in_objects.propA = 'The new value of propA !';

console.log(this_in_objects.propX());
// Returns "The new value of propA !",
// even though 'propA' value was changed AFTER declaring the function,
// returning the value of 'propA' at the time of function execution, not at the time of declaration.
```

This is based on information found on:

- [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions)
- [What is the 'global' object in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627622/what-is-the-global-object-in-nodejs#)
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

I hope this helps and please let me know in the comments if I missed any scenarios where the value of `this` might be different.