# window.parseInt does not compile - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, transpiler

In the below typescript syntax,

```
var strToNum: number = window.parseInt("5");
```

---

gives error:

```
tstut.ts(15,31): error TS2551: Property 'parseInt' does not exist on type 'Window'. Did you mean 'parent'?
```

DOM has,

```
> window.parseInt
 ƒ parseInt() { [native code] }
```

---

Why `tsc` gives transpilation error?

Answer (score 0):

[Window Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) does not contain [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) definition, so TS is unable to find it there. It's a standard built-in function and should be called by a simple call:

```
var strToNum: number = parseInt("5");
```

Comment: But, `window.parseInt("5")` gives 5 on browser console

Comment: parseInt is available on window but should not be used that way because the code would not work in node.js for example . By using window.parseInt you are making code less portable without benefits, Typescript prevents you from making this mistake altogether by marking it as an error.

Comment: That's because in HTML, the global scope is the window object. All global variables belong to the window object, but TS doesn't know about it on transpilation time.

Comment: @WalleCyril Any name(say `parseInt`) you introduce in `.js` file should be under a scope. `parseInt` looks to be under `window` scope. JavaScript execution model is dictionaries of dictionaries. Any name you introduce in `.js` file becomes a property of a dictionary.

Comment: borkovski, you answer is contradicting your comment

Comment: I don't see a contradiction. parseInt() is a global function. Global scope = window scope, but not always. TS won't assume it while transpiling, because it's not always right.

Comment: What is not alway's right? This is where my question is around. Why TypeScript does not respect `window` scope when typescript is superset of javascript. Any valid javascript code should be accepted by `tsc`

Comment: Global scope is not always window object. @WalleCyril gave you an example where it isn't - node.js. That's why Window Object definition does not contain parseInt() function. The same goes for example with console object - it's available in HTML window, but TS won't allow you to call window.console.log(). You can read more about it for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627622/what-is-the-global-object-in-nodejs