# Node.JS global variable declaring when local is same name

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have this code:

```
let manager;
exports.setup = async manager => {
    this.manager = manager;
};
```

This is possible duplicate but every time I saw this, solution was to use `window.manager = manager` to set global variable from inside function. How to do this in Node.JS where is no `window`?
`this.manager` not working, because its seems `this.manager` !== `manager` (the global one)

Comment: You can create Global objects in NodeJS https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html. But that is not really recommended like `global.myVar = 'someValue'`

Comment: `let manager` creates a variable in the current scope, which is the module scope, not the global scope.

Comment: Do you mean [the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627622/what-is-the-global-object-in-nodejs)?

Comment: The real solution here is **Don't mask variables you want to access**

Comment: @Quentin I KNOOOW :D But I am perfectionalist what need it like that :D

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal this not work

Comment: @DavidBubeník `global.manager = manager;` should work but not recommended as @Quentin pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your function parameter hides the local variable in this case.

Consider the following 2 modules:

lib.js

```
let manager = 2;
exports.setup = async manager => {
    this.manager = manager;
};
```

main.js

```
var v = require("./lib.js");
v.setup(5);
console.log(v.manager);
```

This prints `5` because `manager` is the parameter you pass to the function. If you want to obtain the value of the local `manager` (`2` in this example) you need to change the name of the function parameter or remove it entirely.

```
let manager = 2;
exports.setup = async input => {
    this.manager = manager;
};
```

or

```
let manager = 2;
exports.setup = async () => {
    this.manager = manager;
};
```