# What should I do to understanding this case? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, runtime, this, global, read-eval-print-loop

in nodejs REPL

```
$ node
> var a = 10;
undefined
> console.log(this.a);
10
```

---

in execute > node test.js

```js
// test.js
var a = 20;
console.log(this.a);
```

```
$ node test.js
undefined
```

What is different this context from 'repl vs execute js file'?

in execute, console.log(this) -> just {}

not global context

Comment: There is also specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193294/3689450) which I think has the best description. Basically, `this !== global` when you are executing a file. When you do, `this` is the *module* for that file, while in the REPL context `this` is the global object.

Comment: @VLAZ wow! thank you!