# Is there any way to keep an object alive in NextJS whole app

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there any way to keep an object and its content on API side in nextJs?

I want to have a singleton and use it in all my requests. but when I importing create a new instance for each request.

Comment: Do something like this - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use Symbol.for and the [Node global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627622/what-is-the-global-object-in-nodejs) to mantain an instance saved somewhere in the server.