# eval is called indirectly, but get an error

Tags: javascript, eval

Put the code in the file(test.js), then execute `node test.js`. You'll get:

> ReferenceError: val is not defined

If you copy the code directly in the node environment (or a browser console), no error is reported.

```
let val = "global"

function foo2() {
    let val = "local"
    let f = eval
    return f("val")
}
foo2()
```

Comment: "local" does not constitute code, it's just a string.  "The eval() function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 3):

If you read through the MDN [page on `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) you will see:

> if you use the eval function indirectly, by invoking it via a reference other than eval, as of ECMAScript 5 it works in the global scope rather than the local scope.

When you run this code in Node, it will look on the global object for `val` and won't find it because even variables declared on the outside scope are private to the enclosing module in Node - they don’t end up in the global namespace unless you put them there. This causes it the error you noticed.

This, however, will log `global` in Node:

```
global['val'] = "global"

function foo2() {
  let val = "local"
  let f = eval
  return f("val")
}
console.log(foo2())
```

Comment: But why does it only works if you put it explicitly into `global` and not with `let val`?

Comment: @Dmitry because in Node everything is in a module. Variables don't end up in the global scope unless you explicitly put them there. (Not that I'm recommending it), but you can also assign a variable with no `let` or `var` and it will be global too (and the indirect eval above will work). There's a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287201/where-are-vars-stored-in-nodejs)

Comment: So the problem is that `val` is local to the `test` module and `eval` runs on global scope because of it is used indirectly. Clould you add this to your answer for better explanation?