# nodejs: how to use literals in external require?

Tags: node.js

Here is my example:

```
var name="Doe";
var template = require('./template.txt');
```

and template.txt contains:

```
`hello ${name}`
```

I got the error: name is not defined.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think it is not possible as you put it, but template litereals might help you with what you want to do.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates

Comment: ok, but how to keep it external ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you literally want to take JS code from a `.txt` file and run it, so you need the infamous [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
var name="Doe";
var template = require('fs').readFileSync('./template.txt');
template = template.toString().trim();

console.log(eval(template)) // will output: hello Doe
```

Although it can be dangerous to run JS code like this, if the templates are files that are in your control and written by you, then I guess it can be done.

Ofcourse you could simply use a template engine like [EJS](https://ejs.co/) or [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper):

> **The module wrapper**
>   Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will
>   wrap it with a function wrapper that looks like the following:
>
> `(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
>     // Modulecode actually lives in here 
>   });`
>
> By doing this, Node.js achieves a few
>   things:
>
> - **It keeps top-level variables (defined with var, const or let) scoped
>     to the module rather than the global object**.
> - It helps to provide some
>     global-looking variables that are actually specific to the module,
>     such as:
>
>   - The module and exports objects that the implementor can use to export
>       values from the module.
>   - The convenience variables __filename and
>       __dirname, containing the module's absolute filename and directory path.

and [globals](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. This means that
>   within the browser `var something` will define a new global variable. In
>   Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global
>   scope; `var something` inside a Node.js module will be local to that
>   module.

So when we define a variable in one module, the other modules in the program will not have access to that variable, but you can declare your variable without `var` and it will be defined as a global.

More info in this thread: [Where are vars stored in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287201/where-are-vars-stored-in-nodejs)